# Compact Large Objects in Reorganize Index task

Tags: sql-server-2008, maintenance

I'm setting up a maintenance plan in SQL Server 2008 R2.

On the Reorganize Index Task it has an option for "Compact Large Objects".  What does that mean and do I want to turn it on?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Large objects (LOBs) are stored in different "pages".  A page is a small section of a database, typically an 8kb chunk.  For rows that contain LOB columns, the normal page will contain a reference to the LOB page.

From the [alter index manual page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx):

> WITH ( LOB_COMPACTION = { ON | OFF } )
> Specifies that all pages that
> contain large object (LOB) data are compacted. The LOB data types are
> image, text, ntext, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), and
> xml. Compacting this data can improve disk space use. The default is
> ON.

The default is "on" and it's hard to think of a case where you'd want to turn it off.  Perhaps if you had a strict time window for reindexing, and turning LOB compaction off would allow you to meet the window.